# Reduce cannot contain Average() methods in grouping

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb

Just upgraded to v2 and this no longer works; I get a similar error if I try to use Count()

```
public class Deck_Ratings : AbstractIndexCreationTask<DeckRating, Deck_Ratings.ReduceResult>
{
    public class ReduceResult
    {
        public string DeckId { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }
    }

    public Deck_Ratings()
    {
        Map = deckRatings => deckRatings.Select(deckRating => new 
                             { 
                                 deckRating.DeckId, 
                                 deckRating.Rating 
                             });
        Reduce = reduceResults => reduceResults
                                      .GroupBy(reduceResult => reduceResult.DeckId)
                                      .Select(grouping => new 
                                              {
                                                  DeckId = grouping.Key, 
                                                  Rating = grouping.Average(reduceResult => reduceResult.Rating)
                                               });
    }
}
```

Comment: Error message would be nice, also confirm the exact version of v2.0, I'd guess 2230 the stable release?

Comment: The title is the error, if I use Count I get 'Reduce cannot contain Count() methods in grouping'.

Version is 2.0.2230.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aggregates that can be influenced by the size of the reduce batch (such as Count and Average) are prohibited because they will yield the wrong results.  You may have been able to use it under 1.0, but your averages were probably wrong unless you had so few items that they all got done in one reduce batch.  To understand more about reduce batches, read [Map / Reduce - A Visual Explanation](http://ayende.com/blog/4435/map-reduce-a-visual-explanation)

You must count items by summing a 1 for each item.  You must average items by taking a sum of the values as a total, a sum of 1's as a count, and then dividing them.

```
public class Deck_Ratings : AbstractIndexCreationTask<DeckRating, Deck_Ratings.ReduceResult>
{
    public class ReduceResult
    {
        public string DeckId { get; set; }
        public int TotalRating { get; set; }
        public int CountRating { get; set; }
        public double AverageRating { get; set; }
    }

    public Deck_Ratings()
    {
        Map = deckRatings => deckRatings.Select(deckRating => new 
                             { 
                                 deckRating.DeckId,
                                 TotalRating = deckRating.Rating,
                                 CountRating = 1,
                                 AverageRating = 0
                             });
        Reduce = reduceResults => reduceResults
                                      .GroupBy(reduceResult => reduceResult.DeckId)
                                      .Select(grouping => new 
                                              {
                                                  DeckId = grouping.Key, 
                                                  TotalRating = grouping.Sum(reduceResult => reduceResult.TotalRating)
                                                  CountRating = grouping.Sum(reduceResult => reduceResult.CountRating)
                                               })
                                      .Select(x => new
                                               {
                                                  x.DeckId,
                                                  x.TotalRating,
                                                  x.CountRating,
                                                  AverageRating = x.TotalRating / x.CountRating
                                               });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[This is issue RavenDB-783](http://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RavenDB-783). This is expected behavior since v2.0.

Not sure what he recommends as an alternative, though.